Smart TV TCL API
I would like help with pulling the TCL smart TV API, I wanted to know if it is possible?
I tried to pull the TV's API but I couldn't. I used programs like Charles and I couldn't pull the information, I can't find a solution for this

why don't you ask TCL?
